# How to show all images as gallery page in voyager?

Tags: php, voyager

I want to view all images in a gallery folder for my gallery view page. how could I find the code to do it?

```
@foreach(json_decode($gallery) as $gallery)

   <img class="img-responsive gallery" src="{{asset("storage/$gallery->file")}}"/>

@endforeach
```

> Undefined variable: galleries (View: C:\Users\Seyha\kulen-water\resources\views\list\gallery.blade.php)

Comment: The query is not related to the question submitted. Review your error correctly. `galleries` keyword is not present in question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use glob https://www.php.net/glob

something like this:

```
foreach(glob(gallerypath.'*') as $galleryfile){
    echo basename($galleryfile). "\n";
}
```